# What would happen if you detonated a nuclear bomb inside a tank of liquid hydrogen?

Tags: nuclear-physics, estimation, fusion, nuclear-engineering, explosions

Say you had a large bomb - take the 50 megaton Tsar Bomba. You then proceed to place it in the center of a spherical tank containing liquid hydrogen, and then detonate it. Could you start a fusion reaction inside of that tank (and roughly how big would that tank need to be)?

Comment: The fusion process is triggered by compression so just lighting a match isn’t enough.  See http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/

Comment: The only thing that would work is to put it in a tank of U-238.

Comment: My apologies, I meant if I actually detonated the bomb, instead of just lighting a match.

Comment: Only if the tank is made part of a new stage of the radiation implosion device itself, [see here](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Library/Teller.html).

Answer (score 2):

The first ever thermonuclear device, [Ivy Mike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Mike), contained a tank with liquid *deuterium* (heavier isotope of hydrogen, the main isotope, protium, has too small fusion cross-sections). The fusion reactions in this tank were ignited by a fission bomb.

Note, that the main problem for obtaining a significant yield from fusion reactions is to contain fusion fuel long enough for it to fuse, rather than being dispersed by the explosion prematurely (then this would be called a [fizzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzle_(nuclear_explosion))).
So, while simply placing the bomb inside the tank with liquid deuterium will produce *some* fusion reactions, large yields require careful design such as [Teller-Ulam configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teller-Ulam_design).

Answer (score 1):

When the nuclear bomb is ignited, the liquid hydrogen in the tank would evaporate instantly. The evaporation heat of liquid hydrogen of a tank of any reasonable size is negligible compared to the energy released even by a small (Hiroshima) 15kT TNT fission bomb.

Note after comment by @rob: That there won't be any significant fusion of ordinary hydrogen with hydrogen has been answered here: [Fusion: Why deuterium and tritium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87972/129209)

Comment: The question seems to be about nuclear reactions in the hydrogen, not about the hydrogen phase change.

Comment: @rob - The answer is correct. The hydrogen will evaporate and dissipate. That there won't be any significant fusion of ordinary hydrogen with hydrogen has been answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87972/129209